# Output of my JSON result

Tags: javascript, php, json

This code is working fine my concern is its output

Javascript side

```
        function AjaxRetrieve()
        {
            var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value;
            $.get('includes/getChat.php?chat='+uid + '&rid=' + rid + '&name=' + user,function(data)
            {

               $("#clog").html(data);



            });
        }
```

PHP side

```
$sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids LIMIT 1";
          $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
          $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $msg_id->execute();
          $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
          $tbpre = $msgd;
        $sql7 = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbpre."chat_conversation WHERE msgid=:chat";

        $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
        $stmt7->bindValue( 'chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt7->execute();
        $rows = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($rows);
```

the output looks like this:

```
[{"msgid":"1","message_content":"asd","username":"ab","message_time":"2014-04-02 13:58:03","recipient":"cd"}]
```

how can I display the JSON result similar to this:

```
1
asd
ab
2014-04-02
cs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `json` dataType in jQuery, then stringify the object with indentation using `JSON.stringify` and output it in `pre` tags to keep the spaces and newlines

```
function AjaxRetrieve(){
    var rid  = document.getElementById('trg').value,
        data = {chat : uid, rid : rid, name : user};

    $.get('includes/getChat.php', data, function(result) {

        var pre = $('<pre />', {text : JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4)})
        $("#clog").html(pre);

    }, 'json');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/w283W/)

or to just output a list of the values

```
function AjaxRetrieve() {
    var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
        data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};

    $.get('includes/getChat.php', data, function (result) {
        var res = $([]);

        $.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
            res = res.add($('<div />', {text : value}));
        });

        $("#clog").html(res);

    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: hi master @adeneo i tried ur 2nd code snippet and firebug gave this `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a` what wrong with it?

Comment: @user256009 - I really have no way of testing that, but I think I forgot a zero, try it now.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake the output was

`[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]`

Comment: Did you try it now, I changed the answer and it should work ?

Answer (score 3):

Parse response on client side, and display it.

```
$.get('includes/getChat.php?chat='+uid + '&rid=' + rid + '&name=' + user,function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    var temp = obj[0].msgid + "<br>"+ obj[0].message_content + "<br>"+ obj[0].username + "<br>"+ obj[0].message_time + "<br>"+ obj[0].recipient;
        $("#clog").html(temp);
});
```

Comment: what am I missing here the result was `undefined`?

Comment: @user256009 fixed the mistake

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4 offers the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option for use with the `json_encode()` call.

Below is the link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php

$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: This was the output

`"[\n {\n \"message_content\": \"asd\",\n \"username\": \"ab\",\n \"message_time\": \"2014-04-02 13:58:03\",\n \"recipient\": \"cd\"\n }\n]"`

how can I print them as if they were a string instead as an array?

Comment: Try `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: the result is the same =(

Comment: Also when you set your document to `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?